# If formula to return either the name on a related object

Tags: formula, formula-field

I need some help with a formula.

I have a custom object called `Relationships`.

Within this custom object I have multiple lookups (see lookups below). I would like to create one field called `Associated With` which is a text formula field and returns the names of

- `Lookup(Agreement)`
- `Lookup(Legal Entity)`
- `Lookup(Opportunity)`
- `Lookup(Portfolio)`

**Example 1)**

Lookup(Agreement) Populated A

Lookup(Legal Entity) Blank

Lookup(Opportunity) Blank

Lookup(Portfolio)Blank

> outcome "Associated with" A

Example 2)
Lookup(Agreement) Blank

Lookup(Legal Entity) Blank

Lookup(Opportunity) Populated C

Lookup(Portfolio)Blank

> outcome "Associated with" C

Comment: Can you post whatever you have tried and where you are facing issues?

Comment: BLANKVALUE(Opportunity__r.Name, Agreement__r.Name) This only returns Opp Name or Agr name, i am unsure how to build it out to include others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use `BLANKVALUE` here. Note that its [syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) is `BLANKVALUE(expression, substitute_expression)`. You can simply use another `BLANKVALUE` as the `substitute_expression`.

```
BLANKVALUE(Opportunity__r.Name,
    BLANKVALUE(Agreement__r.Name,
        BLANKVALUE(Portfolio__r.Name, Legal_Entity__r.Name)
))
```

---

You could incorporate this into a `HYPERLINK` by using similar logic to create the url and the exact logic as the "friendly name":

```
HYPERLINK(
    "/" & BLANKVALUE(Opportunity__c,
        BLANKVALUE(Agreement__c,
            BLANKVALUE(Portfolio__c, Legal_Entity__c)
    )),
    BLANKVALUE(Opportunity__r.Name,
        BLANKVALUE(Agreement__r.Name,
            BLANKVALUE(Portfolio__r.Name, Legal_Entity__r.Name)
    ))
)
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for providing the example above. Is there a way that I can make that field a hyperlink ? So using the scenarios above and example one the outcome in *associated with" would be "a". Anyway that I can click on this and it takes me to that related record ?

Comment: Yeah I can add that detail.

Comment: Hi Adrian, unfortunately i cant get into my org to test :(. I assume by creating the field a hyperlink  which takes you to the associated record, this functionality would also work if I added this field to a related list ?

Comment: It should work if you include it in a related list, yes.

Comment: Thanks Adrian: wish I could test this . I have looked at this solution all day and couldn't get my head around it. Ask the community and sitting mins get a potential/working solution :)